# Setting global and confirm flags as default for Vim search and replace

Tags: vim

When I use vim's search and replace, I always use the global and confirm flags as demonstrated in the following lines:

```
:%s/foo/bar/gc
:5,10s/foo/bar/gc
:+10s/foo/bar/gc
```

Is there a way to make the g & c flags the default for vim's search and replace?

Comment: There's no option for `c`, only `:set gdefault`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `set gdefault` (see `:help 'gdefault'`) in your `vimrc` but I'm not sure about the confirmation part.

You could also try a custom mapping like this one:

```
nnoremap gs :/gc<Left><Left><Left>
```

that puts the cursor between the `:` and the `/`, ready for you to type the rest.